# Alternative to return in switch-cases

Tags: c++, misra

I want to return something in a switch-case. However, using a return in a switch-case violates MISRA rule 6-4-3, so I'm looking for an alternative.

The rule says: **A switch statement shall be a well-formed switch statement. Return statements shall not be used in switch clauses.**

Code:

```
switch(x) {
  case 0:
   doSomething();
   break;
  case 1:
   return true; // violates MISRA 6-4-3
  case 2:
   doSomething();
   break;
  default:
   doSomething();
   break;
}
```

I know that it can be solved this way:

```
bool var = false;
switch(x) {
  case 0:
   doSomething();
   break;
  case 1:
   var = true;
   break;
  case 2:
   doSomething();
   break;
  default:
   doSomething();
   break;
}
return var;
```

But I would like to solve it without additional code if it is possible.

Comment: Why don't you just put `if (x == 1) return true;` at the begining? And in this case you just skip the whole switch...

Comment: This is how I wanted to do it at the very beginning. But I don't want to remove case 1, so that all cases remain in the switch. But if there is no such solution, then I think this is the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: For clear program flow, you probably should have only one `return` anyway. You could invert the logic, take all code behind the `switch` and put it into an `if` followed by a `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Reading [Misra C++ 2008 Standards](https://www.cppdepend.com/Misra-cpp), nowhere does it say:

> Return statements shall not be used in switch clauses.

But, it does say:

> A function shall have a single point of exit at the end of the function

So, you couldn't use a `return` inside a `case` anyway. You have no choice but to use a local variable to remember the value the `case` wants to return, and then use that variable in the final `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks! In my Code Analyzer it says as an addition under this rule: Return statements shall not be used in switch clauses.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you have more code in the function.

But it's a simple matter to do something like this:

```
bool abort = false;
switch(x) {
  case 0:
   doSomething();
   break;
  case 1:
   abort = true;
   break;
  case 2:
   doSomething();
   break;
  default:
   doSomething();
   break;
}

if (abort)
  return true;
```

Comment: Thanks first of all! As seen in my question, this code fixes the problem with the coding guideline. However, I thought there might be another trick. So that without any additional code outside the switch and without removing case 1, I can achieve the same as with return.

Comment: If you need a `return` statement, and you can't put it in your `switch` statement, then you'll need to put it somewhere else, as I've done.

Answer (score 1):

The multiple `return` rule of the MISRAs has been debated a lot (here on SO and elsewhere). However, if we skip the specifics of that rule and the `switch` format rule, the essence of those rules all boil down to "do not write needlessly complex/spaghetti code just for the heck of it". Which is what you are doing here. Writing even stranger code is not the solution.

What you *should* do is to ditch this whole strange `switch` statement in favour of something more sensible, such as this:

```
if(x == 1) // comment explaining why this is a special case
{
  return true;
}

doSomething();
```

This may not conform to MISRA but it comforms to common sense. Any MISRA warnings remaining are likely because of advisory rules, in which case you can ignore them.

Comment: Thanks! I assume you mean that I should remove the switch completely, right? And instead an if statement for each case?

I solved it by adding an if statement before the switch for the case x==1. The MISRA violation is gone with this and since there is no shorter solution, I'm actually happy with it.

Comment: @KplnMoon The whole point here is that you don't even need a `switch` statement in your specific case. It's hard to talk about a general case. Either way you will have MISRA violation of multiple returns from a function, which is an advisory rule.